# Is there any way to overcome history.push auto decoding by react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using **history.push** by react router to manipulate with URL and facing an issue with **auto decoding**.
What I'm trying to achieve - is the URL properly encoded without encoding slashes, question marks, but with encoding of ",[,] and other characters. For that purpose, I use the encodeURI function, it encodes the URL properly, but then history.push automatically decodes it before changing the browser line.
Is there any way to overcome it?

Versions:

- "react-router": "^5.2.0",
- "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
- "react": "16.13.1",
- "history": "^5.0.0",

Comment: I am facing the same issue.